# ffmeg react native compatibility with ios

Tags: ios, react-native, ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` react native kit to modulate recorded voice pitch tempo etc. I am developing app for Ios using react native.
When I call I get `invariant violation native module cannot be null` error.

I tried different version of `ffmpeg` to check with compatibility but no success. below is the code for `ffmpegexecute`

```
    FFmpegKit.execute('-i /data/home/ubuntu/Desktop/secretfriendblackhat2022-295591-react-native/src/packages/blocks/AudioEqualiser/assets/sample.mp3 -c:v mpeg4 file2.mp4').then(async (session) => {
      const returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
    
      if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
    
        // SUCCESS
    
      } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {
    
        // CANCEL
    
      } else {
    
        // ERROR
    
      }
    });
```